# Animation for "please wait" isn't loading with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this image to tell people that some action is loading: http://problemio.com/img/ajax-loader.gif

Then I put this div on my page to show it:

```
<div id="loading">
  <p><img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" /> Please Wait</p>
</div>
```

Then I put this css for it:

```
#loading 
{ 
    display:none; 
}
```

Then in my jQuery I do this:

```
$("#loading").show();
```

But it just does not render.  Any idea what I am doing wrong and why it does not show up?

Here is a page example where this is supposed to happen: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=216

Thanks!

Comment: @BookOfZeus the code is all there in view-source.  If you need to log in, its testing@problemio.com/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing on Google hrome (by running $("#loading").show(); on developer console) seems to work fine.

Could it be that the element is placed on the bottom of the page and you just don't see it appear ?

If that's the issue try to apply the following styles on your css

```
#loading {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

Also you should probably change the *logic* of the appearance of the block to the following

- Show the loader immediately when the user clicks a link that triggers an ajax call
- Do the ajax call
- Ajax call gets completed (error or success)
- Hide the loading div
- Continue with the error/success handler

  ```
  $('#add_attempted_solution').bind('submit',function() {

  // pre ajax call code

  $("#loading").show();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/auth/check_login.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
          $("#loading").hide();

          // success handling
          ......
          ....
      },
      ...
      error: function() {
          $("#loading").hide();

          // error handling
          ....
          ...
      }
      ...
  })
  ```

  }

Comment: I think the placing might be a problem, but isn't that sort of a thing supposed apprar right in the middle of the screen, no matter where it is in the html?

Comment: oh yeah it appears now - take a look at the link.  But how do I make the js work to make it appear in the AJAX/jQuery? :)

Comment: you know whats happening, the image IS appearing, but for a split second and then it disappears while the AJAX still takes a few seconds to load.  Would you know why that might be happening?

Comment: would it have something to do with the asynchronicity of the AJAX call?  seems its still thinking, but the end of the function is reached pretty quickly.

Comment: do you hide the #loading div anywhere else except inside the error/success ajax callbacks ?

Comment: I think for some reason, the whole function ends before the $('#solutions').html(data); line really finishes.

Comment: if you mean the function for the click event, of course it does. But ajax error/success callbacks get called when the ajax call finish. http://gfxmonk.net/2010/07/04/defer-taming-asynchronous-javascript-with-coffeescript.html#1

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your code somewhere along the line. If you type `javascript:$("#loading").show();` in to your browsers address bar it displays the div fine. Move your JS code to the bottom of the document (before the closing body tag), make sure you have semi-colons where necessary (I've seen a few missing), triple check your code.

More specifically the AJAX request to `/auth/check_login.php` isn't firing the success callback, try using the complete callback.

Comment: I am a little confused - I thought the check_login.php call didn't matter since the show() call I am making is before that.

Comment: Ah yeah, just placed it outside the call, but it is still not rendering :(